# Intuition behind discretization of first and second fundamental form in discrete differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.cse.msu.edu/~ytong/DiscreteFundamentalForms.pdf) with the hope I understand how to discretize the first and second fundamental forms. I think the intuition behind the discretization of the first fundamental form comes from the fact that if we are given the length of each edge of a triangle we can find the angles, hence we can actually retrieve the first fundamental form in that triangle easily, is this correct?

It seems to me that the second fundamental form can be discretized by storing for each face a list of angles, where each angle is the angle between the normal of such face and the normal of the adjecent face.

Can anyone clarify this?